# Switch case that dosent continue in a while loop

Tags: java, switch-statement

```
  int selection;  
  selection = 0;

  
  while (selection != -1)
  {
     selection = menu();

     switch (selection)
     {
     case 1:
        System.out.println("Hur många varor vill du lägga till?");
        int numberOfArticles = input();
        System.out.print("Du har lagt till:  " + numberOfArticles + " varor\n");
        articles = checkFull(articles, numberOfArticles);
        articleNumber = insertArticles(articles, articleNumber, numberOfArticles);
        break;
     case 2:
        System.out.println("Vilken artikel vill du ta bort?");
        removeArticle(articles);
        break;
     case 3:
        System.out.println("Visa artiklar");
        printArticles(articles);
        break;
     case 4:
        System.out.println("Vilken artikel vill du sälja? Hur stort antal vill du sälja?");
        sellArticle(sales, salesDate, articles);
        break;
     case 5:
        System.out.println("Orderhistorik");
        printSales(sales, salesDate);
        break;
     case 6:
        System.out.println("Avsluta");
        System.exit(0);
        break;
     default:
        System.out.print("Felaktig inmatning!\n");
        break;
```

When the user gives a string value then the programs says Wrong value then the program just stops. But when I select a number like 22 or something, the program says Wrong value and the loop continues and gives the user another chance to try. But when it comes to a string input it just stops and don't give the user another chance.

Comment: can you give sample input? Please give at least 2 with input/output as example.

Comment: can you please definition of the ```menu() method```

Answer (score 1):

To end the loop `selection` should equal to -1. I think changing the `default` case like below will solve the problem.

```
default:
        System.out.print("Felaktig inmatning!\n");
        selection = -1;
        break;
```

Then it will exit the loop when the user gives an incorrect value.

Comment: Right way to quit loop can also use break label, but the O/P is trying to assign a String into a integer that is not possible may be o/p is assigning a character.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int input()
   {

      int input;

      input = 0;

      while (input == 0)
      {
         if (keyboard.hasNextInt())
         {
            input = keyboard.nextInt();
            break;
         } else
         {
            input = -1;
            break;

         }

      }

      return input;
   }
```

Comment: This is the method for the input that the user interacts with, I think the problem might be here

Comment: I have solved it now, thx guys n girls for helping noob me.

Comment: This is seems part of your question, please add this part to your question by edit button